# Android: How to use Bamboo CI with Android Maven project

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven, continuous-integration, bamboo

All

I try to implement Bamboo Continues Integration server in my development.
My Android project use Maven "android-with-test" archetype.

How can i build my project om Bamboo.

Could someone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bamboo don't provide android functional testing. Try to use Hudson with Hudson Android emulator plugin http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Android+Emulator+Plugin

It works for me